# CORS, ASP.NET Web API, Kendo UI

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, kendo-ui

I have the following scenario:

- An ASP.NET Web API project (hosted at localhost:8081) which calls my BLL to implement business logic
- An ASP.NET MVC4 project (hosted at localhost:8080) which will form my web layer
- Future plans to add projects for Mobile etc
- I followed the steps to setup a CORS structure to allow cross-domain ajax requests as defined in [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2012/02/20/implementing-cors-support-in-asp-net-web-apis.aspx)

I have an API service to return "somelist" from the database.

- **when I do a simple request through Fiddler I get the right response from the server**

Request:

```
 
    POST http://localhost:8081/api/orgs/getsomelist HTTP/1.1
    User-Agent: Fiddler
    Content-type: application/json
    Host: localhost:8081
    Content-Length: 158

    {"token": "sometoken","kValues": { "userId": "1.0" }}
```

Response:

```
    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    Cache-Control: no-cache
    Pragma: no-cache
    Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
    Expires: -1
    Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
    X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
    X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?WjpcRG9jdW1lbnRzXGNvZGVcSnNyZWVcSnNyZWVcSnNyZWUuQXBpXGFwaVxvcmdzXGdldG15b3Jncw==?=
    X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
    Date: Thu, 13 Dec 2012 22:15:34 GMT
    Content-Length: 315

    {successful JSON response}
```

- **when I do the same thing from by web application (on localhost:8080) using a simple ajax POST call, Fiddler shows 2 requests made, 1 returns 200 success and the other 500 internal server**

```
    Code:
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8;",
        crossDomain: true,
        url: "@urlToConnect",
        withCredentials: true,
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify({token: "sometoken",kValues: { userId: "1.0" }})
    });
```

1st Request: for some reason it shows OPTIONS call instead of POST

```
    OPTIONS http://localhost:8081/api/orgs/getsomelist HTTP/1.1
    Host: localhost:8081
    Connection: keep-alive
    Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
    Origin: http://localhost:8080
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.97 Safari/537.11
    Access-Control-Request-Headers: origin, content-type, accept
    Accept: */*
    Referer: http://localhost:8080/
    Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
    Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
    Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
```

1st Response:

```
    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    Cache-Control: no-cache
    Pragma: no-cache
    Expires: -1
    Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8080
    Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST
    Access-Control-Allow-Headers: origin, content-type, accept
    X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
    X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?WjpcRG9jdW1lbnRzXGNvZGVcSnNyZWVcSnNyZWVcSnNyZWUuQXBpXGFwaVxvcmdzXGdldG15b3Jncw==?=
    X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
    Date: Thu, 13 Dec 2012 22:15:16 GMT
    Content-Length: 0
```

2nd Request:

```
    POST http://localhost:8081/api/orgs/getsomelist HTTP/1.1
    Host: localhost:8081
    Connection: keep-alive
    Content-Length: 127
    Origin: http://localhost:8080
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.97 Safari/537.11
    Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8;
    Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
    Referer: http://localhost:8080/
    Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
    Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
    Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3

    {"token": "sometoken","kValues": { "userId": "1.0" }}
```

2nd Response: my Web API method is not able to get the POSTed JSON data right. I do not get this exception with the same data when POSTed directly on Fiddler in example 1 above

```
    HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
    Cache-Control: no-cache
    Pragma: no-cache
    Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
    Expires: -1
    Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8080
    X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
    X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?WjpcRG9jdW1lbnRzXGNvZGVcSnNyZWVcSnNyZWVcSnNyZWUuQXBpXGFwaVxvcmdzXGdldG15b3Jncw==?=
    X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
    Date: Thu, 13 Dec 2012 22:15:16 GMT
    Content-Length: 906

    {"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"some .NET exception"}
```

- **When I do the same thing using kendoui datasource, I get the same 2 errors, but my request on fiddler shows garbage data, not the JSON I sent**

```
Code:
    dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                read: {
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8;",
                    crossDomain:true,
                    url: "@urlToConnect",
                    withCredentials: true,
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: JSON.stringify({token: "sometoken",kValues: { userId: "1.0" }})
                }
            },
            schema: {
                data: "data",
                type: "json",
                total: "count"
            }
```

Request: JSON.stringify sends weird data

```
    POST http://localhost:8081/orgs/somelist HTTP/1.1
    Host: localhost:8081
    Connection: keep-alive
    Content-Length: 705
    Cache-Control: max-age=0
    Origin: http://localhost:8080
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.97 Safari/537.11
    Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8;
    Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
    Referer: http://localhost:8080/
    Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
    Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
    Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3

    0=%7B&1=%22&2=t&3=o&4=k&5=e&6=n&7=%22&8=%3A&9=%22&10=1&11=F&12=V&13=R&14=A&15=I&16=1&17=E&18=b&19=7&20=%2F&21=%2F&22=M&23=7&24=U&25=A&26=Y&27=h&28=q&29=9&30=i&31=R&32=Z&33=U&34=%2F&35=Y&36=j&37=l&38=o&39=0&40=Q&41=5&42=Z&43=g&44=A&45=H&46=8&47=4&48=%2F&49=5&50=b&51=E&52=g&53=Z&54=F&55=M&56=%2B&57=p&58=Q&59=j&60=0&61=x&62=4&63=w&64=Z&65=6&66=W&67=c&68=T&69=M&70=u&71=Q&72=n&73=K&74=3&75=P&76=x&77=e&78=T&79=C&80=%2F&81=0&82=K&83=K&84=W&85=1&86=w&87=o&88=5&89=2&90=%2B&91=d&92=V&93=R&94=v&95=A&96=%3D&97=%3D&98=%22&99=%2C&100=%22&101=k&102=V&103=a&104=l&105=u&106=e&107=s&108=%22&109=%3A&110=%7B&111=%22&112=u&113=s&114=e&115=r&116=I&117=d&118=%22&119=%3A&120=%22&121=1&122=.&123=0&124=%22&125=%7D&126=%7D
```

I am not sure why the setup doesn't work when I do an ajax call directly or from kendoui datasource

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the method you are posting to take a string for the data ?  Have you tried just using the javascript object as the data ?

Also, the options request you see go across first is because you are making a cross-domain request.  It sends the options "pre-flight" check to get the Access-Control-Allow-Origin to see if it is allowed to send a POST.  If your localhost:8080 isn't in the Access-Control-Allow-Origin, then it won't even send the POST.
Anglin did a nice writeup on enabling crossdomain calls with kendo. He uses odata, but some of the principals apply.
http://www.kendoui.com/blogs/teamblog/posts/11-08-23/cross-domain_queries_to_odata_services_with_jquery.aspx

Comment: Thanks you suggestions, along with another somewhat similar issue on stackoverflow helped me resolve this.